# Mootools, searching dom to see if a class exists, should I worry about doing it multiple times every page

Tags: javascript, dom, mootools, domdocument

I use Mootools and I have quite a few utility functions and stuff that happens on lots of pages. I move these functions into a main JS file so I dont need to remember to add individual aspects to each page, normal sort of a pattern for development I'd imagine.

Now some of these utility functions are only relevant, and indeed will only work, if certain elements are on a page. For instance I have a function which checks for close icons and adds the relevant events to them;

```
$each($$('.closethis'), function(el){ do stuff like add events }
```

This sort of thing happens quite a few times as the page is initiated for close events, hover overs, togglers, alerts all sorts of stuff and everytime its iterating through the dom for certain classes.

Should I be worried about this..? Is this 'sloppy'..? Is there a better way/pattern....?

Thanks

Comment: It won't help for one shot setup function, but depending on the event type you might be better served by [event delegation](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element.Delegation) rather than trying to set up events on every element that matches your criteria.

Comment: In this instance I'm unsure delegation would be any more efficient as I've no idea where the target elements will be so I'd be back to using the entire DOM tree with perhaps the greater overhead of the delegation process, just guessing though!

Answer (score 0):

Every [modern browser](http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname) has a built in function called `getElementsByClassName` that as far as I know Mootools will use under the hood when querying for `'.closethis'`. It's [super fast](http://ejohn.org/blog/getelementsbyclassname-speed-comparison/) so I don't think you need to worry about running it a few times when the page is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

To anwser to you directly: Yes, in my opinion, this is sloppy; but I don't think you have to be worried though.

It wont become a problem, regarding functionality, but to "good style".
Maybe you could write more task specific JavaScript. Write Classes for certain tasks or functionalities. You'll be surprised, how often you'll be re-using classes or general source code and how much time it saves you while developing a webpage.
I'd suggest you to (carefully) read [this](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Class/Class), and [this one](http://www.mootorial.com/wiki/mootorial/09-howtowriteamootoolsclass) and try to benefit from it. 
As this is the "better way/pattern" you've been asking about.

Cheers and happy coding! =)